# How do I autologin a user in a command line based install of linux

Tags: ubuntu, autologin

I am using an [Orangepi zero LTS](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepizerolts/) SBC (Single Board Computer)

I have installed a version of Ubuntu that they provide in their official [software download page](http://www.orangepi.org/downloadresources/orangepizero_zerolts/2020-01-16/orangepizerolts_b0c26da3024b1f6e78f9.html). The image file downloaded from this link is called Orangepizerolts_2.0.8_ubuntu_bionic_server_linux5.4.27.img

However, this is what `uname -a` shows me:

```
Linux orangepizerolts 5.4.27-sunxi #2.0.8 SMP Tue Jun 9 18:36:35 CST 2020 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

This does not show any reference to Ubuntu

For reference this is what an Ubuntu 18.04.6 virtual machine shows me:

```
Linux ubuntu18046opi-VirtualBox 5.4.0-84-generic #94~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 26 23:17:46 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The orangepi board has a single user `orangepi` with sudo privileges (besides the default root user). The OS default image does not have a GUI. How do I make this board log-in to the `orangepi` user by itself when the board powers up? I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/175410/156275) and edited `getty@tty6` but it still asks me for username and password when restarting the board. Is there a general linux method to do this, in case this OS turns out to not be Ubuntu?

I might also eventually install a lightweight GUI desktop on this board, and attach a separate SPI LCD to it and control it through the GUI there. Will I need to do something different for autologin through a GUI?

Edit: after help from @muru in comments I have found this board is currently using ttyS0. I replaced tty6 in the above linked answer with ttyS0

```
sudo systemctl edit getty@ttyS0
```

This is what I write in the nano editor

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -f orangepi' -a orangepi --noclear %I $TERM
```

It still asks for username after a restart

```
*... || long lines of messages || ...*   
Starting kernel ...   
Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.   
Orange Pi 2.0.8 Bionic ttyS0   
orangepizerolts login:
```

Comment: "it still asks me for username and password" in which TTY? Are you on TTY6?

Comment: @muru How do I find out?

Comment: @muru tty command (after I have already logged in) shows this: /dev/ttyS0. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes. So a serial console? You'd need to modify the settings for `ttyS0` instead of `tty6`.

Comment: @muru yes it's a built in serial port on the board and not an ssh log in.

Comment: @muru I replaced tty6 with ttyS0 and this is what I get after restart now:

"... || long lines of messages || ... Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.

Orange Pi 2.0.8 Bionic ttyS0

orangepizerolts login:
"
It's still asking for login